# Node Module Issue

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I'm no expert in Node at all but I'm learning! I recently came across a module that I wanted to include in a project "responsive-backgrounds" https://www.npmjs.com/package/responsive-backgrounds.

All is installed with `npm install --save-dev responsive-backgrounds` and seems fine (i.e. I can see ResponsiveBackgrounds in my minifed and uglified distributon JS). In my main JS file I have:

```
require("responsive-backgrounds");
options = {
    lazy: true,
    transition: 0.5
};
new ResponsiveBackground("#featuredimage", options);
```

However I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: ResponsiveBackground is not defined` when I run my browserified and uglified JS. Am I missing something crucial? I'm sure there are other libraries that do the same job or even better but this is more to understand how to include node modules correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to set variable to the module youre trying to import
try:

```
  let ResponsiveBackground = require("responsive-backgrounds");
    options = {
        lazy: true,
        transition: 0.5
    };
    new ResponsiveBackground("#featuredimage", options);
```

Comment: In my case I used 'var' instead of 'let'. The full code is:
`
    var ResponsiveBackground = require("responsive-backgrounds");

     jQuery(document).ready(function()
     {
 options = {
  lazy: true,
  transition: 0
 };
 new ResponsiveBackground("#featuredimage", options);
    });
` Any idea why 'let' produces an error?

Comment: Oh I didnt realize this was in browser, for some reason thought you were using node.js. From my knowledge the es6 syntax let/const are not supported in browsers yet but in node. here is some documentation on let https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Actually I am using Node so bit confused as to why this fell over. I expected the "let" to be swapped out when I ran "browserify" but this didn't seem to happen. I know this is down to my understanding rather than anything else.

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: nodejs is at v6.11.3 and npm (if that helps) is at 5.3.0

Comment: And just upgraded npm to 5.4.1